# Cocoapods not resolving through Artifactory

Tags: cocoapods, artifactory

Cocoapods not resolving through Artifactory - project not showing up in the remote-cache

I have been following all the instructions in the screencat - Set me up - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eiL3IaQG3Q

I have gem installed cocoapods and cocopods-art.

Added the 'Custom Base URL' = http://localhost:8081/artifactory

Added the following line to have Cocoapods resolve to artifactory:
`pod repo-art add c-remote "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pods/c-remote"`

Added the following to my Podfile:```
vi Podfile

```
plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
  'c-remote'
]

target 'Pods Updater' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RxSwift', '4.4.2'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '4.4.2'
  pod 'Highlightr', '2.1.0'
end
```

Ran: pod install
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.

Yet I do not see the projects in Artifactory. I tried several times. See image below.

[Project not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eENFp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Artifactory running on your Mac (localhost) and Cocoapods installed on the same machine (Mac).